# ng For loop only returning last value from array

Tags: html, angular

I am trying to create a table in Angular with table rows that I would like to populate from a component that contains some string arrays. However, I am coming across an issue where I only end up with one row of data and that piece of data is the last element in the string array.

I have tried implementing a test array where I just create a string array (called testarray in the component code) in the component with dummy data. When I try this with the ng For loop, all of the data pulls through. But when I pull the real data in, it functions as I mentioned above.

** HTML template **

```html
 <table class="table table-hover">
          <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">ID</th>
            <th scope="col">Region</th>
            <th scope="col">Instance Type</th>
            <th scope="col">Instance State</th>
            <th scope="col">Architecture</th>
            <th scope="col">CPU</th>
            <th scope="col">Monitoring</th>
            <th scope="col">Hypervisor</th>
            <th scope="col">Image ID</th>
            <th scope="col">Public IP</th>
          </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody *ngIf="ec2Response">
            <tr *ngFor="let id of ec2Response.instanceIDList; index as i">
              <th scope="row">{{id}}</th>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

** Component Code **

```
export class Ec2Component implements OnInit {

  public ec2Response: Ec2;
  public testarray: string[] = ['23', '45', '25'];

  constructor(private ec2Service: Ec2Service) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.ec2Service.getEC2List().subscribe((data: Ec2) => {
      this.ec2Response = data;
      console.log(this.ec2Response);
    });
  }
}
```

** Service Code **

```
export class S3Service {

  baseURL = environment.apiURL;
  listURL = this.baseURL + '/api/s3/buckets/list';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getS3List() {
    return this.http.get(this.listURL);
  }
}
```

** JSON Response **

```
{
    "instanceID": "XXXXXXXXXXX",
    "instanceState": null,
    "instanceAverageCPU": "NaN",
    "accountCPUUtilization": XXXXXX,
    "instanceAverageNetworkOut": "NaN",
    "accountAverageNetworkOut": XXXXX,
    "instanceIDList": [
        "XXXXXXX",
        "XXXXXXX",
        "XXXXXXX"
    ],
    "imageIDList": [
        "XXXXXXX",
        "XXXXXXX",
        "XXXXXXX",
    ],
}
```

Comment: You have 3 items in your `instanceIDList` array, which are displayed correctly when I recreate your issue using your code. See the StackBlitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ch7erz).

Comment: You are 100% sure that you have more than one row with your real data? and that your real data is structured exactly like your test? If so, then I'm not sure because the for should work for both.

Comment: Your code is working using the hardcoded data which means your api doesnt return what you think. Can you give us the exact response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out what was happening with this problem. The code provided above was working as intended as multiple of the comments have mentioned. The JSON file was pulling through correctly and the code provided above works exactly as intended.

However, in making sure I was only providing the required pieces of code for SO, I omitted 2 additional API calls that happen after the API call in the Component code. These 2 extra calls adjusted my ec2Response object in undesirable ways. So I saw the correct data for a second, a flash when the other calls were made, and the resulting incorrect data.

I put the API calls in question ahead of the getEc2List call and now the data pulls through as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Your response and binding to html is incorrect. Modify one of them i.e.

**HTML:**

```
<table class="table table-hover">
          <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">ID</th>
            <th scope="col">Region</th>
            <th scope="col">Instance Type</th>
            <th scope="col">Instance State</th>
            <th scope="col">Architecture</th>
            <th scope="col">CPU</th>
            <th scope="col">Monitoring</th>
            <th scope="col">Hypervisor</th>
            <th scope="col">Image ID</th>
            <th scope="col">Public IP</th>
          </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody *ngIf="ec2Response">
            <tr *ngFor="let res of ec2Response; index as i">
              <th scope="row">{{res.instanceID}}</th>
              <th scope="row">{{res.instanceAverageCPU}}</th>
                <th scope="row">{{res.instanceState}}</th>
                 <th scope="row">{{res.accountCPUUtilization}}</th>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

**Response:**

```
[
     { 
    "instanceID": "XXXXXXXXXXX",
    "instanceState": "AAAAAA",
    "instanceAverageCPU": "BBBBBBB",
    "accountCPUUtilization": "XXXXXX",
    "instanceAverageNetworkOut": "CCCCC",
    "accountAverageNetworkOut": "XXXXX",
    "instanceIDList": [
        "XXXXXXX",
        "XXXXXXX",
        "XXXXXXX"
    ],
    "imageIDList": [
        "XXXXXXX",
        "XXXXXXX",
        "XXXXXXX",
    ],
   },
   { 
    "instanceID": "XXXXXXXXXXX",
    "instanceState": null,
    "instanceAverageCPU": "NaN",
    "accountCPUUtilization": "XXXXXX",
    "instanceAverageNetworkOut": "NaN",
    "accountAverageNetworkOut": "XXXXX",
    "instanceIDList": [
        "XXXXXXX",
        "XXXXXXX",
        "XXXXXXX"
    ],
    "imageIDList": [
        "XXXXXXX",
        "XXXXXXX",
        "XXXXXXX",
    ],
   }
   ]
```

**Result:**

[image]